I'm having a problem with installing livekit plugins openai in visual code studio
This is the main code that I use for my final project in college
import asyncio

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from livekit.agents import AutoSubscribe, JobContext, WorkerOptions, cli, llm
from livekit.agents.voice_assistant import VoiceAssistant
from livekit.plugins import openai, silero
from api import AssistantFnc

load_dotenv()


async def entrypoint(ctx: JobContext):
    initial_ctx = llm.ChatContext().append(
        role="system",
        text=(
            "You are a voice assistant created by LiveKit. Your interface with users will be voice. "
            "You should use short and concise responses, and avoiding usage of unpronouncable punctuation."
        ),
    )
    await ctx.connect(auto_subscribe=AutoSubscribe.AUDIO_ONLY)
    fnc_ctx = AssistantFnc()

    assitant = VoiceAssistant(
        vad=silero.VAD.load(),
        stt=openai.STT(),
        llm=openai.LLM(),
        tts=openai.TTS(),
        chat_ctx=initial_ctx,
        fnc_ctx=fnc_ctx,
    )
    assitant.start(ctx.room)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await assitant.say("Hey, how can I help you today!", allow_interruptions=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli.run_app(WorkerOptions(entrypoint_fnc=entrypoint))

This is the error i get
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\Desktop\fyp\LiveKit-AI-Voice-Assitant\ai\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\Desktop\fyp\LiveKit-AI-Voice-Assitant\ai\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\Desktop\fyp\LiveKit-AI-Voice-Assitant\ai\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tbubv9cq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tbubv9cq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires    
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\Haziq\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tbubv9cq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 33, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 27, in get_version
      KeyError: '__version__'
      [end of output]

I tried to use both pip and pip3 installation guide but i still doesn't fix it, I already installed openai and the livekit agent. I also tried to search the solution but didn't find anything related to this.
